# Generic method to set the reference variable in the caller function to null

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am writing a utility method to cleanly release a reference to a COM object.

```
public class ComUtils {
    public static void ReleaseObj(ref object comObj)
    {
        if (comObj != null)
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObj);
            comObj = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call this method like this:

```
CommandData cmdData;
//cmdData = Acquire a CommandData object
ComUtils.ReleaseObj(ref cmdData);
```

I get a compiler error that says

> cannot convert from ref CommandData to ref object

Casting CommandData into object will lose the purpose of the generic method, which has to set the reference variable to null, after releasing it.

Is there a solution?
I am using VS 2005, .NET 2.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for generics:

```
public static void ReleaseObj<T>(ref T comObj) where T : class
{
    if (comObj != null)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObj);
        comObj = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes; generics were introduced in 2.0.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly ! Thanks. Was just thinking of an improvement, like whether it is possible to pass a variable number of arguments of any class by reference, like this: public static void ReleaseAll<T>(params ref T[] comObj) where T : class. The compiler says that the params parameter can not be declared as ref or out. Is there a solution in C# 2.0 or if not, then in any other .NET version? I wanted to call it like: ReleaseAll(obj1, obj2, obj3) etc.

Comment: Other than a bunch of overloads, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifically asks, "**Generic method** to take an object parameter [...]." emphasis mine.

You don't have a generic method.  You have a non-generic method.  You're accepting an *object*, when you want to accept a parameter where that parameter is *of any type*, which is accomplished through *a generic method*.  If you make the method generic, it'll work.

Comment: Ok. Just out of curiosity, isn't the object of any class assignable to a variable of type object? I mean, the compiler allows: CommandData cmdData = new CommandData(); and then object o = cmdData; without requiring a cast. Why then it insists on a cast when the parameter is being passed by reference to another function?

Comment: @AllSolutions You can assign a *value* of any type to a *variable* of type `object`.  When you have a `ref` parameter then the argument isn't a *value*, it's a *variable*.  Your `CommandData` *variable* can only have `CommandData` *values* assigned to it, so if you treated it as an `object` variable (which you'd be doing by passing it to as a `ref object` then you could assign objects that aren't of type `CommandData` to it.